# Android Enterprises Device Enrollment Stuck with NodeJs Generated QR Code with Service Account Authentication

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, android-enterprise, emm

As mentioned in the google documents i have tested the following process

URL to quick start: `https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb#scrollTo=pjHfDSb8BoBP`

1. Create Enterprise
2. Create Policy
3. Enroll the device

Then I have used the NODEJS API of Android Enterprises to develop the server based solution, which is working fine as per the documentation for all the functions such as get, create, delete the policy, devices, enterprises.

The issue i am facing is with the QR code generated from NODE application, when i scan the QR code generated from NODEJS application, the device got stuck at system update.

Following is my Policy update function

```
 router.post('/update/:id', async function(req, res) {
      const {title,policy_body,update_mask,enroll_url} = req.body;
      // here we are callng the android managment API to and then the response we will update to database
      const amApiBody  = {
        name: policy_body.name,
        updateMask:update_mask,
        requestBody:policy_body
      }
    const policy_update_response =  await  amApi.updatePolicy(amApiBody);
      const p =  await  policyModel.update(req.params.id,title,policy_update_response,enroll_url);
    res.json(p)
 });
```

AmAPI file

```
    this.updatePolicy = async function (body)
    { 
            const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
                scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement'],
            });

            const authClient = await auth.getClient();
            google.options({auth: authClient});
            
            // Get the list of available policies
            const res = await androidmanagement.enterprises.policies.patch(body);
            console.log('requestFinalBody=',body);
            return res.data;

    }
```

Following is my policy data obtained by running above function

```
policy_create_response= {
  name: 'enterprises/LC019rjnor/policies/policy1',
  version: '14',
  applications: [
    {
      packageName: 'com.google.samples.apps.iosched',
      installType: 'FORCE_INSTALLED',
      autoUpdateMode: 'AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY'
    },
    {
      packageName: 'com.dekaisheng.courier',
      installType: 'FORCE_INSTALLED',
      autoUpdateMode: 'AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY'
    }
  ],
  keyguardDisabledFeatures: [ 'KEYGUARD_DISABLED_FEATURE_UNSPECIFIED' ],
  defaultPermissionPolicy: 'GRANT',
  uninstallAppsDisabled: true,
  keyguardDisabled: true,
  tetheringConfigDisabled: true,
  dataRoamingDisabled: true,
  networkEscapeHatchEnabled: true,
  bluetoothDisabled: true,
  debuggingFeaturesAllowed: true,
  funDisabled: true,
  kioskCustomLauncherEnabled: true
}
```

Note i have exported the variable to the terminal as follows before running the app, the auth.json is the service account credential file.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/Mac/Projects/wajid/mdm/server/env/auth.json"
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in nodeJS API I was passing wrong property name of Policy value in the request body.

Code before fix

```
        parent: this.getParent(policyName),
        requestBody:{
            “name”: “my_policy"
        }
```

Code after fix

```
 parent: this.getParent(policyName),
        requestBody:{
            "policyName”: “my_policy"
        }
```